# Вопрос по экспорту JSON объекта в mysql

Tags: php, mysql, json

Всем доброго дня. Вопрос про php mysql. Проблема следующая: некие данные, которые находятся в JSON объекте. Этот объект нужно отправить в базу данных mysql(с этим проблем нет), однако при экспорте в БД, срезаются слэши в тексте(все скриншоты прилагаю). При определенном условии необходимо вытаскивать JSON и методом JSON_decode расшифровывать его. Однако тк слэши срезаются, текст не расшифровывается. Если кто то сталкивался с этой проблемой и решил ее, буду благодарен за подсказку. Заранее спасибо.
[image: Оригинальный объект]
[image: Объект, полученный из базы]

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: Если не принципиально хранить в юникоде. Попробуйте изначально сохранять в базу без экранирования и без юникода. Например так: json_encode($value, 64|256);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Символ `\` в MySQL является символом квотирования. См. [String Literals](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-literals.html).

Т.к. JSON передаётся серверу как текст, этот символ следует предварительно (ещё на клиенте) удвоить.

Альтернативный вариант - изменить сессионный SQL Mode (вообще или на один запрос) и установить `NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES`.